# Download bunch of files in Bg

Tags: ios, ios5, networking

I need to download bunch of files (~600mb) from an ftp server.

The question is how would be best to implement that?
The simplest solution would be to pause\resume the download each time the app goes back to foreground.
The problem with that of course is that the users won't be able to initiate the download, lock the iPad, and come back when it's all done.

Does iOS allow downloading that amount of files totally in the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only allowed to run in background for downloading content if you are a newsstand app and downloading the issues of your magazine. See [this document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW24) for reference. I assume your app is not a newsstand app.

However, you can also ask for extra time to finish your task when your app moves to the background. Checkout [`beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler%3a) method of `UIApplication` to see how you can do that. It will give you about 10 minutes to finish your task. It probably won't be sufficient to download all of the files but it will allow your app to download some of them.

I guess you can also send a local push notification to the user when your background execution time is about to finish to let him open the app again and continue the download. However, I have not sent any local notifications before so I am not sure if it is possible to send them while executing a background task.